# Ldap Auth as Rest Controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

[image: phpLDAPadmin Schema]
I have configured a remote Ldap server, I have a frontend and the desired behavior is: When the user fills the login form in frontend, I want to send credentials to backend via a controller then backend should perform a lookup to my ldap server and return a response to identify the user like his id and null if user is not found.

I am having a hard time about wrapping my head around the concept and all examples are either using a local ldap or redirecting to login form on backend. I do not want the login form on backend or secure some endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am doing in my project:

> in application.properties file

1. server,protocol=http://
2. server.host.name=
3. server.ip=
4. server.port=
5. server.url=

Then from RESTController I am calling this service:

```
  @Service
    public class ldapService
    {
    @Value("${ldap.server.protocol}")
        private String LDAP_SERVER_PROTOCOL;

        @Value("${ldap.server.ip}")
        private String LDAP_SERVER_IP;

        @Value("${ldap.server.port}")
        private int LDAP_SERVER_PORT;

        @Value("${ldap.service.url}")
        private String LDAP_SERVICE_URL;

    public String authenticate(LoginDto loginDto){

            UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials(loginDto.getUserName(), loginDto.getPassword());

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpEntity<UserCredentials> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<UserCredentials>(userCredentials);

            final String FINAL_URL = LDAP_SERVER_PROTOCOL + LDAP_SERVER_IP + LDAP_SERVER_PORT + LDAP_SERVICE_URL;

            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(FINAL_URL);


            ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST,
                    httpEntity, ResponseDto.class);

            HttpStatus statusCode = exchange.getStatusCode();
            ResponseDto responseDto = exchange.getBody();

            // check if response OK and is user validated.
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.OK)
    {
    //switch according to HttpStatus
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment, this is what I aim to do but I had trouble understanding some points in your solution: What is LDAP_SERVER_PROTOCOL and LDAP_SERVICE_URL how can I learn my protocol and service url? I know my ip and port and I use openldap. I also did not understand how the lookup occurs, how does it know which folder to check in server. What will the server send as a response on success? I just want to return user's id.

Comment: for ex im my project: LDAP_SERVER_PROTOCOL=http:// and LDAP_SERVICE_URL=packageName/methodName(abc/authenticate) which will be hit by exchange method of rest template on execution.I will try to upload the code where the actual call to the remote LDAP server is made with given userName and password.

Comment: I would appreciate that, really didn't get the LDAP query, where do we specify folder and username. Also why do we add the packageName/methodName to url, how can server understand that or do I need to configure something on server? I only installed OpenLdap and phpLdapAdmin.